# keep file order using jquery file upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I was looking at the upload script here:

http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/

It is using jquery file upload to upload multiple files at once. I would like to know how to pass the order of the files that were selected to the upload.php script. ie. if you have 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, 4.jpg, and 4 finishes uploading first, can upload.php receive a variable that tells it that it is the 4th image that was selected? Does jquery file upload have a way of adding the order to the form action perhaps?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it was a really easy fix once I found it. There is a variable in the jquery.fileupload.js file called sequentialUploads. Set it to true, and it will force the order of uploads to be the order in which the files are selected.

Comment: sequentialUploads is a solution with a penalty: you will not upload files simultaneously anymore, so it'll be a lot slower.

Answer (score 0):

It should automatically upload and read the data in the order it was received once it hits the upload.php layer. So just make sure you upload the files in the order you want them.

Comment: Yeah, but when you upload all at once, the upload.php file receives the files in the order in which they finish uploading. So 4.jpg may finish first, but if the file is indeed named 4.jpg, I want to retain that it is 4th in the sort order when I write to the database.